# Spring-MVC: How can I display errors while using an AbstractCommandController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have ajax requests that come into my controller and my validation is working great. In the controller I call a failure jsp page if there is a failure. The only problem is that I have no idea how I can output the errors to the user on the failure.jsp page. I don't have access to the form tags of spring obviously. What should you do in this scenario?

Edit: All I really want to know is how I can access the binding errors on a JSP page when I'm using an AbstractCommandController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done in the past is use HTTP headers to send back messages to the AJAX requester (the XMLHTTPRequest object). You will not get a full binding and validation support this way, but it's a simple way to pass messages.

Another option that will give you the full power of Spring binding and validation is as follows. I'm assuming you're submitting a form via AJAX. You could do the standard spring binding and validation, and in the case of an error, send back and replace the form with the exception messages next to the problem input. This way you can leverage the full power of Spring binding and validation while getting the AJAX goodness that you want. This would require you to separate your form into a separate JSP page, so you could just return that form on AJAX submission and error.

In response the comment

> My issue is just how to access the
>   BindingErrors from a JSP if I'm using
>   an AbstractCommandController. Ajax
>   isn't really that important in the
>   equation. I just didn't want to use a
>   formController because it didn't make
>   sense.

I *think* you can simply set a variable in your model like this:

```
ModelAndView.addObject(this.getCommandName(), errors)
```

This would be done in AbstractCommandController's

```
protected abstract ModelAndView handle(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object command,
        BindException errors)
    throws Exception
```

method. Be sure the name of the model attribute is the name of your command (set in the setCommandName method).

This is untested and from memory.

Comment: My issue is just how to access the BindingErrors from a JSP if I'm using an AbstractCommandController. Ajax isn't really that important in the equation. I just didn't want to use a formController because it didn't make sense. If you can answer that then I'll give you the correct answer thing for this question.

Comment: Sorry this took forever to approve but here you are. Nice answer sir.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the BindException object for errors (and also catch and handle exceptions), and return information about them in your Ajax response.  If you're using JSON, you could pair a list of error information with an "errors" key.  The front-end would then need to check for and display these errors.

Comment: How would I check the bindException object?

Comment: I think what I'm asking is not how I figure this out in the controller, but rather how I can let my view have access to the bind object. I'm not sure if this controller supports it or not.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't give the view the bind object directly, you'd have to map it manually -- use the BindException to create a list of errors (in whatever format you choose) that the client side can process and display.  In the past I have added a pair to the response JSON with a key of "errors" and a value list of all the errors that occurred.